# Android, Google Analitics: how to implement page view tracking on "/quit" application exit?

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracking, pageviews

I need to track my Android application exit as a page view.
My application has several activities, but there is no hierarchy, so there is not an unique exit point.

My understanding is that "application exit" means another application is on top of mine, hiding it completely. So if my application is no more visible, there is an "application exit".
Is my understanding correct?

So, how could I track this "application exit" with Google Analytics?

Looking forward for advice.
Thank you.